# How to get slate indentation with increasing depth

Tags: reactjs, slate, react-slate

how to get numbered list when Tab key press on slate editor currently i get only one numbered list ?

```
export const toggleBlock = (editor, format) => {
  const isActive = isBlockActive(editor, format);
  const isList = LIST_TYPES.includes(format);

  Transforms.unwrapNodes(editor, {
    match: (n) =>
      LIST_TYPES.includes(
        !Editor.isEditor(n) && SlateElement.isElement(n) && n.type
      ),
    split: true,
  });
  const newProperties = {
    type: isActive ? 'paragraph' : isList ? 'list-item' : format,
  };
  Transforms.setNodes(editor, newProperties);

  if (!isActive && isList) {
    const block = { type: format, children: [] };
    Transforms.wrapNodes(editor, block);
  }
};
```